# Calling async function on Swift From AppDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, appdelegate

I have implemented a completion handler to deal with the async function. This completion handler returns a value which is crucial to set a rootViewController's VC type.
Problem that I'm having deals with the fact that AppDelegate wants the rootViewController be set as swiftly as possible. When it returns from non-blocking function. It crashes without waiting for Completion Handler.

## 1

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication,....)-> Bool{
  ...
  someAsyncNetworkCall{(err,data){
     guard let ability = data else return { fatalError() }
     if (ability == 'ALLOW'){
       self.window?.rootViewController = stateVC
     }else{
       self.window?.rootViewController = someOtherVC
     }
  }
}

func someAsyncNetworkCall(completionHandler:@escaping(Error?,Any?)->()){
   ...
  //Networking code{
    completionHandler(nil, data)
  } 

}
```

ViewController is not set at time. It crashes before even completionHandler gets time to get back.

## 2

```
func someAsyncNetworkCall(completionHandler:@escaping(Error?,String?)->()){
   ...
  //Networking code{
    completionHandler(nil, data)
  } 
   
  //Some stuff 
  completionHandler(nil,'ALLOW')
}
```

This doesn't crash but it is pretty useless but completion Handler is called twice here. I Couldn't find anything useful while researching.

Comment: You have a serious problem with app architecture, not code - why on earth would you need to make a network call to create a root view controller? Why cant you assign a root view controller, and present/push another one when the network call finishes?

Comment: Believe me, I did that first thing when I got the code. Hooked rootViewController to new VC and pushed VC depending on conditional that was passed by Network call but there were some functionality that didn't work. There are 100 thousands lines of code written by some other dev. It is so hardly coupled that It will take months to re-implement and Unit/integrate test. I'm planing to do it but for time being this is the easiest way to do it without disrupting my BOSS request.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't going to be the easiest way because as you've seen it will crash.  You must set the root view controller straight away.  If you then want to change it once the async process is complete you can.  Just from a UI point of view it's bad design.  What happens if the async process is delayed?  What is the user left looking at?

Comment: I agree with all of these comments on the app architecture.  In hopes of making your Friday a bit more manageable I would suggest creating a root view controller that cannot be interacted with (or just shows "Loading..." with a spinner, etc).  When your async call gets back present the proper view controller.

Comment: AppDelegate has some click listener for TabBar :/ . I literally need to start from scratch here. Implementation is just poor.